# Using https native module within express app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an express app and I'm trying to avoid using third-party libraries to make an HTTP request to an API.

However, the request is made no matter the endpoint the user visits.

Acceptance criteria:
If the user hits `/`, nothing should happen
If the user hits `/cars/:car`, then it should make the call.

Now If I hit the root (/) it also makes the request.

```
app.get('/cars/:car', (req, res) => {
  const { car } = req.params;
  try {
    https.get(`${theAPI}/cars/${car}`, resp => {
      let data
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error:', err);
  }
});
```

I will appreciate your help and advice. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: what do you mean "made no matter the endpoint"?
can you share more code?

Comment: When I go to /whatever it makes also the HTTP request when it should only make it when I go to /cars/something. Thanks :D

Comment: can you share the whole file?